# process txt file to csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a txt file of boston housing price, I have copied it from archive UCI Machine Learning because dataset is no more available, its look like this:

```
 0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65.20  4.0900   1  296.0  15.30 396.90   4.98  24.00
 0.02731   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  6.4210  78.90  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80 396.90   9.14  21.60
 0.02729   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  7.1850  61.10  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80 392.83   4.03  34.70
 0.03237   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.9980  45.80  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 394.63   2.94  33.40
 0.06905   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  7.1470  54.20  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 396.90   5.33  36.20
 0.02985   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.4300  58.70  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70 394.12   5.21  28.70
 0.08829  12.50   7.870  0  0.5240  6.0120  66.60  5.5605   5  311.0  15.20 395.60  12.43  22.90
```

as there is no **Separator option** (tab, comma, space) for me to **Separated by** and paste it to MS Excel, so I can make its **csv** file, is there any simple code so I can process it quickly via pandas or numpy

Comment: You can use pandas read_csv with sep='\s+'. Have a look at the doc.

Comment: @Bill Bell but its not a csv file

Comment: @MuhammadHassan - It is no problem if `txt` file, use `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)`

Comment: Alternative should be `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)`

Comment: pandas can't tell what the contents of the file are from the file's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) working with `txt` nice too with `header=None` for new header with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for write to file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df.to_csv('file1.txt', index=False, header=None)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
df.to_csv('file1.txt', index=False, header=None)
```